# Last Text within span tag gets cut in safari version 10.0.2

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, safari

Issue on Safari version 10.0.2, on mouseover I am changing the color of the text in span tag but span doesn't covers whole text and last letter in sentence gets cut so color does not applied to last letter(s). If I remove word-space it resolves the issue.

Any ideas as to why this isn't working as I'd expect?

[Please find screen shot attachment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AoY6u.png)`enter code here`

```
<div id="mainDiv">
            <span>The best preparation for tomorrow is doing your best today.</span>
</div>
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/45eqLmhs/4/)

Comment: on safari for windows 5.1.7 is not reproducible

Comment: I don' want to change HTML structure and it is not working on Mac OS Safari.

Comment: I use Safari 10.1 on Mac OS 10.12 and cannot reproduce this problem. It seems like a bug in Safari 10.0.2

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Can you please check updated jsFiddle link This issue occurs due word spacing but I need to keep word spacing same given in example. Please suggest

Answer (score 0):

Add Display property for span tag.

```
span{display: block; width: 100%}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Can you please check this updated jsFiddle link? If i have to follow the structure as given then display: block; does not work.

Comment: If you want to change the color of all span(s), why don't you try adding hover effect on the **#mainDiv**    `#mainDiv:hover span{color: red}`

Comment: I want change the color of text with in span on mouseover, that's why issue occurs.

Comment: Thank you for reply! Please check updated jsFiddle link so that you can get idea related to problem...on safari 10.0.2.